# Why do the Binder Cumulants of different system sizes intersect at the critical point?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, ising-model, spin-models

When Monte Carlo simulations are performed for spin models (Ising model etc.) the critical temperature can be found by simulating for different lattice sizes and plotting the Binder Cumulant for them. The intersection point of these plots gives the Critical temperature. Why is it so? And can the same be said for order parameter (magnetization)?